# Debugging & profiling a runtime-loaded module

Tags: c, loadlibrary, dlopen

I need to load and run a C module using `dlopen()` / `LoadLibrary()`, and be able to review extensive profiling & debugging information of the hosted module *only* (*not* the host program), via a live log displayed as part of the host:

1. How exactly would I go about extracting stack state and profiling info from the hosted module, at runtime? `gprof` and `gdb`? And doing so without slowing things down awfully?
2. Could any of the debugging and profiling information that comes back, be mixed up (i.e. between host and hosted), provided that I compile both the host and hosted modules with the correct, respective compiler switches? I need a completely clean separation of log data i.e. just the hosted module.